# Log object's aggregation path using System.Diagnostics

Tags: c#, logging, aggregation, system.diagnostics, tracelistener

Imagine, there is a dependency between objects (and classes =) ):

```cs
class IrrelevantClass
{
    public IrrelevantClass(UserClass user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    public void InvokeUserClassMethod()
    {
        _user.UseDependencyClass();
    }

    private UserClass _user;
}

[Root]  // Log should trace all the dependencies since that root.
class UserClass
{
    public A(DependencyClass dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void UseDependencyClass()
    {
        // some computation...
        _dependency.MethodWithLogging();
    }

    private DependencyClass _dependency;
}

class DependencyClass
{
    public void MethodWithLogging()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Very clever logging message.");
    }
}
```

How can I make the following code

```cs
DependencyClass dependency = new DependencyClass();
UserClass user = new UserClass(dependency);
IrrelevantClass irrelevantObject = new IrrelevantClass(user);
irrelevantObject.InvokeUserClassMethod();
```

result in a log message that looks like that:

> 17:12:04 - [UserClass] - [DependencyClass] - Information: Very clever logging message.

I have vague thoughts about the solution — probably it can be constructed from the stack trace.

Comment: What if you have a deeper dependency chain, like 2-3 deep? Do you always simply want to know only the immediate parent?

Comment: @crush: great thought-provoking question =) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call GetType().Name to get the class name that's it

```
  System.Diagnostics.EventLog appLog = 
        new System.Diagnostics.EventLog() ;
    appLog.Source = "My super program";
    appLog.WriteEntry(String.format("17:12:04 - [{0}] - [{1}] - Information: Very clever logging message.", this.GetType().Name, _dependency.GetType().Name));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion!
I have added a slight clarification of the question.

Comment: Hi, i need to know why do you want to do this exactly ? logging purposes, exception management,... ?

Comment: For logging purposes. The object that does logging can be used in different classes and the hierarchy of classes may be useful to understand flow of control.
All the exceptions are logged with maximum information (including a full stack trace).